# Expected height of the shortest person within a random sample

Tags: probability

(A) Suppose we choose *n* people at random from the population, and the heights of the people within the population are normally distributed with average height *m* and standard deviation *s*. What would be the expected height of the shortest person within the sample?

(B) Then, suppose we remove the shortest person from the original sample as well as *k* other people chosen at random (these may not include the shortest person, who has already been removed). That is, there is now (*n* - *k* - 1) people in the group, where (*n* - *k* - 1) > 0. What would be the expected height of the shortest person within this new group?

(C) If step (B) were repeated *i* times, such that each time the new group contains [*n* - *i*(*k* + 1)] people, what would be the expected height of the shortest person within the group at the *i*th step? Again, assume here that [*n* - *i*(*k* + 1)] > 0.

From my understanding, the answer to (A) is quite straightforward and may be calculated based on our knowledge of the normal distribution. However, I have no way of answering (B) and (C) - at least without a computer simulation. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Even part (A) is a difficult question for a normal distribution. See [this paper](http://www.untruth.org/~josh/math/normal-min.pdf) about the minimum of independent normal variables.

Comment: This is the same question you already asked. What was wrong with my answer?

Comment: The original question was flagged for being unclear - so I have re-worded it.

Comment: @AngusMurray Why didn't you simply edit the original question to reword it?

Comment: Please answer my question:. What was wrong with my answer? Was the answer not clear? Please undelete your previous question so I could save my answer. It disappeared with your question.

Comment: I apologise for deleting the question - I am relatively new to this forum and I was unaware of the normal protocol. I will try to recover the deleted answer.

Comment: Just for a second, please. Then you can delete it again.

Comment: ????????? I worked on that answer more than one hour. You ignored and deleted my answer. This is not nice.

Comment: @zoli Please find original question undeleted

Comment: Now, delete it.  I copied my answer here. Please consider my answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question A**

So, we have $n$ random measurements and we are interested in the distribution (and the mean) of the smallest element. Usually the lament is denoted by $X_{(1)}$.

In order to get the pdf of $X_{(1)}$ at an $a$, we have to calculate

$$f_{(1)}(a)=\lim_{\Delta a\to 0}\frac1{\Delta a} P(X_{(1)}\in[a,a+\Delta a)).$$

S0, let's proceed the following way

$$P(X_{(1)}\in[a,a+\Delta a))=P(\Phi( a)\le \Phi(X_{(1)})<\Phi(a+\Delta a))=$$
$$=P(\Phi( a)\le U_{1}<\Phi(a+\Delta a))$$
where $\Phi$ is the gaussian cdf with parameters $m$ and $s$ and $U_{(1)}$ is the smallest element of a sample of $100$ independent and uniformly distributed random variables (uniform over, of course $[0,1]$).

[It is known that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution) for the smallest element of a sample of size $100$ of i.i.d uniform random variables the probability to fall in an interval is

$$P(\Phi( a)\le U_{1}<\Phi(a+\Delta a))=n(1-\Phi(a))^{n-1}(\Phi(a+\Delta a)-\Phi(a)).$$

As a result, the pdf of the smallest element is

$$f_{(1)}(a)=\lim_{\Delta a\to 0}\frac1{\Delta a}n(1-\Phi(a))^{n-1}(\Phi(a+\Delta a)-\Phi(a))=n(1-\Phi(a))^{n-1}\phi(a).$$
Where $\phi$ is the cdf belonging to $\Phi$.

In the case of the standard normal distribution ($m=0$ and $s=1$) the cdf looks like this

[image]

The mean of this distribution is

$$n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}a(1-\Phi(a))^{n-1}\phi(a)\ da.$$

This integral can be evaluated only by numerical methods. For $n=100$ $m=0$ and $s=1$ (which data don't really belong to height measurements) the mean is $\approx -2.5$.

As far as the largest number, the solution is symmetrical...

---

**Question B**

Let's assume that we omit the smallest number and $1$ more randomly selected samples from our set of height measurements. The probability that we omit the second smallest data is $\frac{1}{n-1}$ and the probability that don't remove that element is then $\frac{n-2}{n-1}$.

So, the pdf of the random variable we seek for is

$$f^1=\frac{n-2}{n-1}f_{(2)}+\frac1{n-1}f_{(3)}$$

where $f_{(2)}$ and $f_{(3)}$ are the densities belonging to the order statistic of the original sample of $n$ element. For both of these densities we can use the argumentation above except that we have to use the formulas given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution).

If we omit $k$ further samples the the first step is to calculate the probabilities that we omit the remaining smallest element will be $X_{(2)}$ or $X_{(3)}$ or $X_{(4)}$ and so on.

Having these probabilities we can use the argumentation given in the answer answer in part **A**. Again, the necessary formulas can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution).

**Question C**

Suppose that we have $n=\ell (k+1)+1$ numbered balls sitting on the table in the order of their numbers. Now, remove the first ball and $k$ other balls randomly. The balls are still in order but $k+1$ of them are missing. Remove the ball of the smallest number again an $k$ other balls, and so on. Do this until only one ball remains. Since we had to repeat the operation $\ell$ times the first $\ell$ balls will disappear for sure. Now, we have to calculate the probabilities that the number on the remaining ball is $\ell+1$ or $\ell+2$, ...  If you know these probabilities then you will know the probabilities that $X_{(\ell+1)}$ or $X_{(\ell+2)}$ or ... will be the order statistic whose pdf will have to be calculated.

The calculation, again is based on answer **A** and the formulas given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Order_statistics_sampled_from_a_uniform_distribution).

Comment: I appreciate the time you've taken to write this out. You have basically answered part (A) for me. Thank you.

Comment: OK, I gave further hints to help...